# Image included in canvas does not appear on generated image

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm using Canvas to let my users "design" an add that later is transformed into an image to be displayed on my website. In this design, the users can add their logo. I'm using this function to add the logo to the canvas:

```
function canvasLogo(){
var x = 70;
var y = 70;
// var width = 500;
// var height = 500;

var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
    var imageWidth = imageObj.width;
    var imageHeight = imageObj.height;
    if (imageHeight > imageWidth) {

        imageWidth = (imageWidth / imageHeight) * 490;
        imageHeight = 490;
    } else {

        imageHeight = (imageHeight / imageWidth) * 490;
        imageWidth = 490;
    }

    x = x + (500 - imageWidth) / 2;
    y = y + (500 - imageHeight) / 2;
    roundedImage(70, 70, 500, 500, 30, 0, 0, 30);
    global.kanvas.ctx.clip();
    global.kanvas.ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    global.kanvas.ctx.fillRect(70, 70, 500, 500);
    global.kanvas.ctx.drawImage(imageObj, x, y, imageWidth, imageHeight);
    console.log("Logo cargado");
};
imageObj.src = global.kanvas.logo;
```

}

And then the users add other things like text and colors and finally when they click the button to create the add I use:

```
function crearAnuncio(elm){
if($("#advanced-wizard").valid() && global.form.idMetodoPago > 0){
    NProgress.start();
    global.kanvas.size = "z";
    setTimeout(function(){
        render();
        global.kanvas.ctx.scale(1*3,1*3);
        setTimeout(function(){
            kanv = document.getElementById(global.kanvas.canvasId);
            var imgB = kanv.toDataURL("image/png");
            var serialForm = $("#advanced-wizard").serialize();
            var arguments = serialForm+"&file="+encodeURIComponent(imgB);
            deliver(arguments);
            console.log(global.request.response);
            // Run paypal
            if(global.form.idMetodoPago==1){
                document.getElementById('paypal_process').submit();
            } else {
                global.request.response = '';
                deliver_site(arguments, "success.php");
                window.location.href="success.php?token="+global.request.response;
            }
            NProgress.done();
        }, 550);
    },150);
} else {
    alert('Seleccione el método de pago ');
}
```

}

To transform the canvas into a png which is then displayed on my site.

The thing is that sometimes (haven't been able to replicate the error myself and the clients say it only happens "sometimes") their logo is not rendered in the final image (text and colors do). The space for the logo is just blank. The clients tell me that they could see their logo on the canvas before pressing the generate button.

It doesn't appear to be related to operative system or browser since the same computer sometimes creates the add alright and sometimes without the logo. I thought it was my server so I changed and upgraded the hosting and it still happened.

Any idea on what could be going wrong?

Comment: Please try to find a reliable way to reproduce the bug. Otherwise we can not help you.

Comment: you should always save() context before clipping, and restore() after the operation, for one thing. Hard to say anything withoutthe render() code, but there might be too much code for a S.O. question... Put some order in your code (avoid hard coded constants, break functions into smaller generic ones) and maybe the bug will show. Good luck !